# Unable to fetch Cookie values while using Ajax Modal Popup extender

Tags: c#, asp.net, cookies, ajaxcontroltoolkit, modalpopupextender

Here's the scenario:
I've a page(**Homepage.aspx**) which has a button.
When clicked i used to Pass some values in cookies inside _Click method of the button in .CS file and then open a different aspx page(**Detail_Report.aspx**) where i was retrieving the values from the cookies and then display the content of the page which uses the values i've retrieved.

Now recently i've decided to implement Ajax pop-up extender to show the **Detail_Report.aspx** page.

I'm able to do this using the following code:

```
    <asp:modalpopupextender id="ModalPopupExtender1" 
            runat="server" cancelcontrolid="btnCancel" 
            okcontrolid="btnOkay" targetcontrolid="Detail_Report" 
            popupcontrolid="DR" popupdraghandlecontrolid="PopupHeader" 
            drag="true" backgroundcssclass="ModalPopupBG">
        </asp:modalpopupextender>

      <div class="popupConfirmation" id="DR" style="display: none">
    <iframe id="frameeditexpanse" src="DetailReport.aspx" frameborder="1">
    </iframe>
    <div class="popup_Buttons" style="display: none">
        <input id="btnOkay" type="button" value="Done2" />
        <input id="btnCancel" type="button" value="Cancel2" />
    </div>
</div>
```

Here's the button declaration:

```
<asp:Button ID="Detail_Report" runat="server" 
                style="z-index: 1; left: 60px; top: 110px; position: absolute; width: 230px;" 
                Text="Detail Report" Font-Bold="True" BorderStyle="Solid" 
                Enabled="False" onclick="Detail_Report_Click"/>
```

And this is what i've inside my onClick Method:

```
protected void Detail_Report_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //string javaScript = "<script language=JavaScript>\n" + "DetailReport();\n" + "</script>";
            Response.Cookies["proj"].Value = c_ProjName.Text.ToString();
            Response.Cookies["LOB"].Value = c_LOB.Text.ToString();
            Response.Cookies["release"].Value = c_ReleaseName1.Text.ToString();
            Response.Cookies["country"].Value = c_CountryName.Text.ToString();
            Response.Cookies["testenvkey"].Value = testenvkey.ToString();
            //ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "Detail_Report_Click", javaScript);
```

**Now my problem is Pop-up is coming up, but i'm unable to fetch the values from cookies as those are blank. As a result My Detail_Report.aspx page is not displaying correctly**

Comment: Same problem here. any solution found?

Comment: Not yet.... Searched google one whole day, but couldn't find a single post which can help...

Comment: i have found the work around on this let me give you example.

Answer (score 0):

```
%If Session("ChildLoad") = "True" Then%>
 'Model Extender and panel
  <%end if%>
```

and then on the load of child page check the session status if its true then pick the values from session or cookies but to do that you need to enable post back on your main page.

Idea behind is

when you refresh the main page it will fire the load event from child page as well.

Comment: I got your point, but lemme explain my scenario a bit more clearly.
On my homepage, i have some dropdowns. Now only after i select the values from all the dropdowns, i'll be clicking on the button to call the child page and will be passing a value in the cookie as per the selection i've made in dropdowns.

I'm able to do this properly if i'm not using Ajax modal pop-up, but when i'm using Ajax pop-up, at the time when my homepage is loaded it loads the child page too, & because i didn't pass any value to the cookies, child page load was unsuccessful as it uses the value in cookie to fetch data

Comment: but if you put the check on the home page load while using session you can avoid the load of child page. and when you load the child page fire the main page load event as well but this time with the session check load the child page as-well so you can use the cookies value on the child page load.